# How to Regex.IsMatch at a specified offset in .NET?

Tags: .net, regex

Suppose I want to match `"abc"` within the string `s` only if it occurs exactly at index `n`.

```
int n = 2;
Console.WriteLine(new Regex("abc").IsMatch("01abc", n)); // true
Console.WriteLine(new Regex("abc").IsMatch("0123abc", n)); // true (but want false)
Console.WriteLine(new Regex("^abc").IsMatch("01abc", n)); // false (but want true)
```

Seems that the only way to achieve this *without using Substring on the input* is something like this:

```
var match = new Regex("abc").Match("0123abc", n);
Console.WriteLine(match.Success && match.Index == n);
```

This isn't too bad, except that when there is no match at the starting offset then the *entire* input will be scanned unnecessarily, which is probably slower for most regexes than actually creating a substring prior to the match. (I didn't time it though).

Am I missing an obvious overload or setting that would restrict a match to the supplied offset only?

Comment: :O I wanted to do exactly this too, but I didn't think it was possible. Thanks for asking this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\G`:

```
var match = new Regex(@"\Gabc").Match("0123abc", n);
```

From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3583dcyh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> If you want to restrict a match so that it begins at a particular character position in the string and the regular expression engine does not scan the remainder of the string for a match, anchor the regular expression with a `\G`...  This restricts the match so it must start exactly at `startat`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\G` at the start of your regex to ensure it matches at the beginning.

(`^` doesn't work).

Testing in PowerShell:

```
PS> $r = [regex]"\Gabc"
PS> $r.IsMatch("01abc",2)
True
PS> $r.IsMatch("012abc",2)
False
```

Comment: Could you show an example please? I've shown one that doesn't work. ^ doesn't match at offsets.

Comment: @romkyns: That shows I should test first :-(. But it appears `\G` does work... updating answer.